# Delete space-expanded "tab" in Vim with one keystroke?

Tags: vim

I edit [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) code with Vim.

With the <kbd>tab</kbd> key I get four spaces inserted for indentation. How can I delete those spaces with one "Backspace"(?) stroke - instead of four?

There has to be some "set" option for that...

Here is my .vimrc:

```
set autoindent
set ts=4
set sw=4
set et
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to back up one tab stop. This actually moves the whole line to the left one tab stop; <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> does the same thing to the right. Note that these keystrokes only work in Insert mode (use `<<` and `>>` for the equivalent in Command mode).

Answer (score 35):

```
set softtabstop=4
```

Comment: IMO this is exactly what the OP asked for. Deserves more upvotes.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Did not know about this, and this was exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 5):

*tl;dr: `set tabstop=4 softtabstop=-1 shiftwidth=0 expandtab`*

*short form: `set ts=4 sts=-1 sw=0 et`*

#### Explanation

If you set `softtabstop` (or `sts`) to `-1` it will automatically behave the
 same as `tabstop` (`ts`), which will save you some hassle if you change tabbing a lot.  Setting `shiftwidth` (`sw`) to `0` should effectively make
 that the same as `tabstop` as well.

#### In Detail

`shiftwidth` `sw`

> Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent. Used for `cindent`, <kbd>>></kbd>, <kbd><<</kbd>, etc.
>   **When zero the `tabstop` value will be used.**

`tabstop` `ts`

> Number of spaces that a  in the file counts for.  Also see
>   [:retab](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab) command, and
>   `softtabstop` option.

`softtabstop` `sts`

> Number of spaces that a <kbd>Tab</kbd> counts for while performing editing
>   operations, like inserting a <kbd>Tab</kbd> or using <kbd>BS</kbd>.  It
>   *feels* like <kbd>Tab</kbd>s are being inserted, while in fact a mix of spaces
>   and s are used.  This is useful to keep the `tabs` is setting at its
>   standard value, while being able to edit like it is set to `sts`.  **When
>   `sts` is negative, the value of `shiftwidth` is used.** This will save you
>   some hassle if you change tabstops a lot.  When `expandtab` is not set, the
>   number of spaces is minimized by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>s.

`expandtab` `et`

> In Insert mode: Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a .
>   Spaces are used in indents with the <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> commands
>   and when `autoindent` is on.  To insert a real tab when `expandtab` is on,
>   use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  See also
>   [:retab](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab)

Comment: Neat, I've been using vim for years but the inheritance of sts/sw/ts never caught my eye.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [GreedyBackspace.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1390) for someone who wanted something like this.  I don't personally use it so it's been a while since I've updated it.  I haven't received any bug reports on it lately, though.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

1. You could 'retab' all whitespaces so they're replaced with tabs. That way they could be easily deleted.
2. You could (this is untested, so I'm just proposing ideas here) make a function which 'execute's in normal mode 4 times the backspace key. Then map it to something. However, it has no way of knowing whether it will delete spaces or some important characters, so this is potentially unsafe.
3. '4X' will delete the last 4 characters (that's big X, not small, small one will act like the Del key'.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is `<<`, repeat with a `.`

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser. Although i agree with your answer being a vi user myself. Your answer is short, does not explain why you suggest what you are suggesting and why you are not suggesting something that fits the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked using the **expand tabs** setting in your VIM?

```
:set noet
```

I usually prefer keeping the tabs on while working on the files.
When it is required, I replace the tabs to 4 spaces or as many as required.

```
:%s/<ctrl+V><tab>/    /g
                  ----
```

As a small bonus, your source file is shorter by 3 chars per tab `:-)`

Comment: oh, I have et because I have to expand tabs - i think - because code I edit was initially written that way. now I'm just following that convention.

Comment: You could still do what i say and restore spaces at the end (when you have to give the file back to the repository)

Comment: Maybe you could have a vim function that expanded them to tabs on open and collapsed them to spaces on closing?  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is a really unhelpful answer--it needlessly reopens the tabs-vs-spaces debate, without actually providing any useful information.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there's a way.  Once the tab key is expanded to four spaces, vim has no way of knowing they were ever a tab.

Comment: -1: Lack of imagination.